# yarn4 global add alternative

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

recently I have upgraded my repo to Yarn4 from version 1.22.9. I have a following command in docker file

```
RUN yarn global add serve@13.0.2
```

The yarn global commands have been removed from version 2 onwards.

Which command should I use to install dependency globally?

Thanks in advance.